# Use TSql to find the original table that a column within a view came from

Tags: sql-server

If I create a view such as:

```
create view View1 as
select Table1.Column1 from Table1
```

Is there a way to find Table1 given only the name View1.  It's easy enough to find the columns within View1 by querying sys.columns where the object_id is equal to the object_id of the view name from sys.objects but how can you tell what is the underlying table that the column within the view came from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql) with @browse_information_mode = 1. This will return a result set with the underlying table name and column name of each view column along with other meta-data.  Source information will be `NULL` for view columns derived from expressions but other meta-data (e.g. data type information) will be included.

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set
      @tsql=N'SELECT * FROM dbo.YourView;'
    , @params = NULL
    , @browse_information_mode = 1;
```

Note that `sp_describe_first_result_set` was introduced in SQL Server 2012 so this will not work in prior versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Awesome!

If the original view statement was 

`select Table1.Column1, Table2.Column1 from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.Column2 = Table2.Column2`

is there a way to tell that Table1 is the base table that the 'from' is based upon?

Comment: @tdinpsp, the meta-data will show the source of the columns of exposed by the view. There isn't really a notion of a "base" table for an inner join query; results will be the same regardless of whether a table is specified in `FROM` or `JOIN` and the source will be that specified in the `SELECT` clause.